# Differentiate the Function: $y=\frac{ae^x+b}{ce^x+d}$

Tags: calculus

$y=\frac{ae^x+b}{ce^x+d}$

$\frac{(ce^x+d)\cdot [ae^x+b]'-[(ae^x+b)\cdot[ce^x+d]'}{(ce^x+d)^2}$

numerator only shown (') indicates find the derivative

$(ce^x+d)\cdot(a[e^x]'+(e^x)[a]')+1)-[(ae^x+b)\cdot (c[e^x]'+e^x[c]')+1]$

$(ce^x+d)\cdot(ae^x+(e^x))+1)-[(ae^x+b)\cdot (ce^x+e^x)+1]$

$\frac{(ace^x)^2+de^x+dae^x+de^x+1-[(ace^x)^2(ae^x)^2(bce^x)(be^x)+1]}{(ce^x+d)^2}$

Am I doing this problem correctly? I got to this point and was confused as to how to simplify. Can someone help me?

Comment: $a,b,c$ and $d$ are constants.  Their derivative should be zero, not one.

Comment: So unless there are two letters adjacent to each other multiple times in a problem, one assumes they are constants?

Comment: Remember, the quotient rule is that for $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ we have the derivative being $\frac{f'(x) \cdot g(x) + f(x) \cdot g'(x)}{[g(x)]^2}$. Also recall that the derivative of a constant is zero.

Comment: @Cetshwayo Unless $a,b,c$ and $d$ are functions that depend on $x$, they are to be treated as constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{ae^x+b}{ce^x+d}\right]$$
$$=\frac{\left(ce^x+d\right)\frac{d}{dx}\left[ae^x+b\right]-\left(ae^x+b\right)\frac{d}{dx}\left[ce^x+d\right]}{\left(ce^x+d\right)^2}$$
$$=\frac{\left(ce^x+d\right)\left(ae^x\right)-\left(ae^x+b\right)\left(ce^x\right)}{\left(ce^x+d\right)^2}$$
$$=\frac{e^x\left(ace^x+ad-ace^x-bc\right)}{\left(ce^x+d\right)^2}$$
$$=\frac{e^x\left(ad-bc\right)}{\left(ce^x+d\right)^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Okay so you have $y(x)= \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, I have a hard time remembering the rule for differentiating a quotient so this is what I usually do:

$$y(x)= \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = f(x)\cdot G(x)$$
where $G(x)=\frac{1}{g(x)}$. Then apply the rule for differentiating a product (which I do remember):

$$\frac {\partial y}{\partial dx} = y' = f'(x)\cdot G(x) + f(x)\cdot G'(x)$$

then:

$$ G'(x) = \frac {\partial G}{\partial x} \frac{1}{g(x)} = \frac {\partial G}{\partial x} g(x)^{-1} = -g(x)^{-2}g'(x)$$.

Inserting into $y'$ yields the quotient rule:

$$ y' = \frac{f'(x)}{g(x)} - \frac {f(x)\cdot g'(x)}{g(x)^2} = \frac{f'(x)g(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2}$$

Now we can move on to your specific case:

$$f = ae^x+b$$
$$f' = ae^x$$
$$g = ce^x+d$$
$$g' = ce^x$$

. Inserting into the quotient rule for $y'$:
$$y' = \frac{f'(x)g(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2} = \frac{ae^x(ce^x+d) - (ae^x+b)ce^x}{(ce^x+d)^2}$$

Expand numerator, collect terms and simplify:

$$y' = \frac{(ad-bc)e^x}{(ce^x+d)^2}$$

Comment: The "Inserting into the above line" Can you show more steps?

Comment: I am asking you to show me how you distributed the $ae^x$ and $ce^x$ on the second to last line.

Comment: You forgot to distribute the $-1$ in front of the term $(ae^x+b)ce^x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{ae^x(ce^x+d)-(ae^x+b)ce^x}{(ce^x+d)^2}=
\frac{(ad-bc)e^x}{(ce^x+d)^2}.$$

Comment: Regarding this part of the problem I am stuck. this is what I have $(ae^x\cdot ce^x+d\cdot ae^x-[ae^x\cdot ce^x+b\cdot ce^x])$ are using the associative property to rearrange them?

Comment: $ae^x(ce^x+d)-(ae^x+b)ce^x=ae^xce^x+dae^x-ae^xce^x-bce^x$

Answer (score 0):

Another method would be to use logarithmic differentiation. Your function $$y=\frac{ae^x+b}{ce^x+d} $$ is identical to $$\ln(y)=\ln\bigg(\frac{ae^x+b}{ce^x+d}\bigg)=\ln(ae^x+b)-\ln(ce^x+d). $$ We find the differentials for both variables $x$ and $y$. $$\frac{1}{y}dy=\bigg(\frac{ae^x}{ae^x+b}-\frac{ce^x}{ce^x+d}\bigg)dx.$$ We solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and find $$\frac{dy}{dx}=y\bigg(\frac{ae^x}{ae^x+b}-\frac{ce^x}{ce^x+d}\bigg). $$ Substituting the initial equation for $y$ yields a solution of $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{ae^x+b}{ce^x+d}\bigg(\frac{ae^x}{ae^x+b}-\frac{ce^x}{ce^x+d}\bigg). $$ We simplify then distribute through $$\begin{align}\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{ae^x+b}{ce^x+d}\bigg(\frac{ae^x(ce^x+d)-ce^x(ae^x+b)}{(ae^x+b)(ce^x+d)}\bigg)\\ &= \frac{e^x[ace^x+ad-(ace^x+bc)]}{(ce^x+d)^2}\\ &=\frac{e^x(ad-bc)}{(ce^x+d)^2}.\end{align}$$ This is your answer.

Comment: Didn't think of that but it seems overly complicated for the situation. Op doesn't even seem to know to distribute $a(b+c)$ (although I forgot the -1 *grumble*)  so I wouldn't hold my breath on them knowing the basic logarithm rules. :\

Comment: You may be correct; however, I cannot speak for the OP. Albeit my method may be tedious, it is not uncommon for other users to have a question similar to the one above. By answering the same question with different, seemingly unrelated techniques, we help others understand the problem in a new, and unique way.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{ae^x+b}{ce^x+d}=\frac{a}{c}-\frac{ad-bc}{c}(ce^x+d)^{-1}$ implies $f'(x)=(ad-bc)e^x(ce^x+d)^{-2}$.